# SDK error message on IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I am new to this community and have this problem:

I downloaded the IntelliJ IDEA IDE for Windows (x64) and i can not run a single line of code, there always comes the error message:

> Cannot start compiler: the SDK is not specified for module "XY".
>   Specify the SDK at Project Structure dialog.

I followed the [instructions on their Website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/sdk.html) and downloaded the SDK for Windows x64 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Now I used to set up everything, but it doesn't work as planned. In fact it is the same error as before.

I am glad for any help, thanks! :)

Comment: For me I had the wrong folder opened in Android Studio!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First make sure you have installed JDK on your system. Open the command line and type: `java -version`.
You should get something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Then open your project in IntelliJ IDEA and go to **Project Structure → Project** tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on *Windows OS*) and add new JDK by providing its local path like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`:

[image]

Comment: I believe the *Project SDK* in the *Project tab* is what needs to be set to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but if it is **still** not working, check the run configuration for the project you are trying to run (assuming you are using IntelliJ):

- right click on your main Application file and choose "Modify Run Configuration." You can also do this by navigating into the file itself and clicking on the play button on the left side of the class definition.
- You should see "Build and Run Options," under which there will be a dropdown menu allowing you to select between different versions of the JDK. Sometimes this can get out of sync with the JDK you have selected in the Project Settings or Gradle/Maven settings.